# Why are there no Java classes in Spring Boot starters JARs?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

[image]

On springboot 2.0 I want to know why spring authorities do this?

spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.0.0.jar  why not content????

Comment: Because there is no content. That applies to all startes, they only have a pom to declare the dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum your comment should be an answer (THE answer!)

Answer (score 0):

This is done on purpose.
The code for the auto-configuration is contained in the `spring-boot` module; Spring Boot starters are "just" POMs bringing all the dependencies that will trigger the auto-configuration for that use case.

Third party starters (i.e. maintained by the community) can ship auto-configuration code as well.

You can learn more about [how to create your own starter and why they're structured like this in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-custom-starter).

Comment: thanks，i go to read springboot document, hope you Said in detail to write